# fileupload.postedfile.filename not working with firefox

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Hi is there any problem with fire fox? I'm not able to get the file name using

fileupload.postedfile.filename in firefox. But the same thing working find in ie.

What is the problem?

Regards,
Nagu

Answer (score 5):

What do you get? IIRC, Firefox sends the filename without path (IE sends full path); but that should still be enough to get a name. If you use `Path.GetFileName(filename)` you should have the same answer from either...

Comment: Path.GetFileName() ? is there any method like that?